# In number ring $D=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am stuck in reading Marcus book, Chapter 3.

Let $D=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

I need to verify that $$(1-\sqrt{-5})=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})(3,1-\sqrt{-5}).$$

I proved that $(1+\sqrt{-5})=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})(3,1+\sqrt{-5})$.

According to Marcus book,  $(2,1+\sqrt{-5}),(3,1+\sqrt{-5}),(3,1-\sqrt{-5})$ are prime ideals. Why?

I know the target is to prove the factorization of ideal $(6)$ is unique of prime ideals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll do $\langle2,1+\sqrt 5 \rangle$. You'll get the idea.

The idea is that the quotient by a prime ideal should yield a domain:

So we have the ring $D=\mathbb Z[\sqrt 5]$ which I'm going to describe as $\mathbb Z[x]/\langle x^2-5\rangle$. We are further quotienting by the ideal $I=\langle 2, 1+x \rangle$ in this ring. Noticing that $x^2-5 = (x-1)(x+1)-2\cdot2\in\langle 2, 1+x \rangle$, we have

$$D/I\cong \mathbb Z[x]/\langle 2,1+x\rangle/\langle x^2-5 \rangle \cong \mathbb Z[x]/\langle 2, x+1 \rangle \cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,$$

which is a domain.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x^2-5=(x-1)(x+1)-4?$

Comment: and $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle 2,x+1\rangle$ has more than $2$ elements ? it has $0,1,x$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 $x$ and $1$ are equivalent because $x-1=x+1-2\in \langle 2,x+1\rangle$..

Comment: @user1952009 And you can see the last isomorphism easily by quotienting first by $2$ to get $\mathbb Z_2[x]/\langle x+1\rangle \cong \mathbb Z_2$..

Comment: so I can do $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle 2,x+1 \rangle =  \mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle 2 \rangle / \langle x+1 \rangle =\mathbb{Z}_2[x] / \langle x+1 \rangle$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Exactly. There is a slight abuse of notation here though. That last quotient should not be by $\langle x+1\rangle$ but by $\langle \tilde x+1\rangle$ where $\tilde x$ is the image of $x$ in $\mathbb Z[x]/\langle 2 \rangle$ under the quotient map but so long as we all know what we're doing it's tolerated.

Comment: So, if I take $(3,1+\sqrt{-5})$ , then I can say $\mathbb{ Z}[x]/<3,x+1>\simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]/<3>/<3,x+1>/<3>\simeq \mathbb {Z_3}[x]/<x'+1>\simeq \mathbb {Z/3Z}$

Comment: What about $(1-\sqrt{-5})$? how to verify the above equation,  how to write $3(1+\sqrt{-5}) D$ in terms of $1-\sqrt{-5}$ after expanding  the R.H.S

Comment: Sorry I meant $2+x$ instead of $1+x$, so we can use $I=(3,2+x)$ .I depend on $x^2-5=(x+2)(x-2)-3.3$.

Comment: @Leonardo Yes, that's correct. You probably meant to write $x^2+5=(x+2)(x-2)+3\cdot 3$ though.